# change the value of objects of the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js

Here's is my array

```
Array1 = [{year: "2013", fruit: "banana", quantity: 1},{year: "2014", fruit: "orange", quantity: 1},{year: "2014", fruit: "banana", quantity: 2}]
```

And my function to duplicate Array1:

```
var Array2 = Array1; 
for (var i = 0, len = Array1.length; i < len; i++) {
    Array2[i] = Array1[i];
}
```

But I'd like to change in Array2 all the values my key "year" and put the value "AllYear":

```
Array2 = [{year: "AllYear", fruit: "banana", quantity: 1},{year: "AllYear", fruit: "orange", quantity: 1},{year: "2014", fruit: "banana", quantity: 2}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), but make sure you return a new object:

```
var Array2 = Array1.map(function (el) {
  return { fruit: el.fruit, year: 'AllYear', quantity: el.quantity }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2mz08ybj/3/)

Comment: this will change both arrays IMO.

Answer (score 0):

//js

```
 var Array2 = Array1 
  for (var i = 0, len = Array1.length; i < len; i++) {
    Array2[i].year = "AllYear";
}
```

refer this solution : [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8mkLb5bv/)

I hope this will help !

Comment: This will modify the original array, because both `Array2` and `Array1` point to the exact same array.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
Array2 = Array1.slice(0); //copy array1 elements to array2
Array2 = Array2.map(function (el) {
var copy = {};
 for (var attr in el) {
        if (el.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = el[attr];
    }
  copy.year = 'AllYear';
  return copy ;
});
```

Comment: yes i know i just given an idea . in that every object has to be clonned. let me modify the answer

Comment: :) I made the same mistake.

Comment: your answer it better than mine.. true :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var Array2 = Array1;
$.each(Array2,function(index,value) {
  value.year = "AllYear";
});//returns what you excepted
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explain how it works, and describe when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.